# django python: missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, django

I am trying to define a function that has 4 arguments but I am facing a problem with my forth argument and I am pretty sure it is something stupid. Here is my code:

views.py:

```
def create_recording(request, slug, inspection_id, component_id):
    inspection = get_object_or_404(Inspection, pk=inspection_id)
    plant = get_object_or_404(Plant, slug=slug)
    component=get_object_or_404(Component, pk=component_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RecordingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            recording = form.save(commit=False)
            recording.plant = plant
            recording.inspection=inspection
            recording.component=component
            recording.save()
            return redirect('data:inspection_detail', slug=plant.slug, inspection_id=inspection.id)
    else:
        form = RecordingForm()
    context = {'form': form, 'plant':plant,'inspection':inspection}
    template = 'data/create_recording.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

here is my html file:

```
<a href="{% url 'data:create_recording' slug=plant.slug inspection_id=inspection.id component_id=1 %}">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Chaiir
   </button> 
</a>
<a href="{% url 'data:create_recording' slug=plant.slug inspection_id=inspection.id component_id=2 %}">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Table
   </button> 
</a>
```

url:

```
url(r'^plants/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/inspection(?P<inspection_id>[0-9]+)/create_recording$', views.create_recording, name='create_recording'),
```

and I get the following error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:create_recording() missing 1 required positional argument: 'component_id'
```

Comment: The HTML template passes keyword-style arguments to `create_recording()`, while the function itself accepts plain positional arguments.  You should probably change one or the other so they both use the same style.

Comment: what is the problem with id=1? what error it is showing when you pass id=1?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is here

```
<a href="{% url 'data:create_recording' slug=plant.slug inspection_id=2 %}">
```

You do not sending `component_id` which the view is expecting.

EDIT:
There is an issue in your URL:

```
url(r'^plants/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/inspection(?P<inspection_id>[0-9]+)/create_recording/(?P<component_id>[\d]+)$', views.create_recording, name='create_recording'),
```

Comment: you are right! but this was just a typo in my question I corrected it! Now it is correct

Comment: so your issue is still not resolved? If so, It might be an issue with your URL pattern. can you edit the question to show the url pattern?

Comment: Did you notice you are not capturing component_id in the url pattern? If you do not capture it, the view would not receive it. Hence the exception. Check the edit.

Comment: it works but it does not take the component_id=1 I have to add it!

Comment: I hope you are not expect someone else to help fix your code just by saying its not working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144738/discussion-between-george-and-karthikr).